# Word for person who is always dizzy or high

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is a single word for a person who is always dizzy or high? I am sure it is not the same as a person who drinks a lot.
Here Always means without an end.

Comment: Do you mean someone who is always using drugs?

Comment: Dizzy and high are pretty may have similar effects, but they are very different things.

Comment: If drugs aren't central to the person's behaviour, I'd go for [ditzy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditzy), otherwise [druggie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/druggie)

Comment: @T.E.D . Ya i think you are right . could you please explain it ?

Comment: "Dizzy and high" will yield a whole raft and flavor of words. "Dizzy or high" implies a more innocent and general condition. If you edit your question to refine your intent - the answers can be more precise. The same goes with always - are you meaning continually (without end) or habitually (with great repetition).

Comment: I would choose 'Space Cadet' or even 'Moon Unit' but sadly those are two-word answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A person that is dizzy or high WITHOUT drugs might be described as "giddy."

(But maybe the associated adrenaline is a "drug.")

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refer to someone who is always on drugs, you can call them a *stoner*. This primarily [refers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoner) to someone who uses cannabis (marijuana), but you could apply it to mean anyone on drugs.

A more formal term is [*addict*](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/addict):

> a person who is unable to stop taking harmful drugs

Comment: In some dialects of English getting "stoned" means the same as getting "drunk". Trinidadian, for example. Caused no end of giggles whenever my university friend suggested we go get stoned.

Comment: The use of addict is general to all abusers - depressants, narcotics, stimulants, etc... It's hard to argue that one meaning of high is synonymous with stoner - but it doesn't imply the "dizzy" very much for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to be clever, you could describe someone who is always dizzy as [vertiginous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vertiginous).  This is how I describe myself when having bouts of vertigo.